# Output Audio missing in Dialogflow response

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have an agent setup in Dialogflow with few intents. The response of every user inputs will be only from Google assistant. I have kept no default responses for any intent. The audio output is null as shown in the image. Is it possible to get audio output base64 string if the response is only Google assistant.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Its intents and not indents

Comment: Thanks for your valuable findings.

Comment: Are you using fulfillment or are you doing this as one of the responses? Can you update your question to show a screen shot of an Intent that is doing this?

Comment: @Prisoner I doing this as one of the responses. Added a screenshot for reference

Comment: Did you do anything to get it to show the Output Audio? I'm a little confused - you want to get what the spoken part sounds like, or you're trying to set audio to play?

Comment: Ya, I enabled text to speech in edit agent section. I am able to play audio for responses "Default" but not for "Google assistant". Is this the actual option provided by Dialogflow